# PHP MYSQL request through JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an image gallery, at the moment I limit the results to 10.

What I'm trying to do, through jQuery, is on click of the 'Load more Results' button,
Load the next 10 rows(images) in the database.

at the moment I use a class query.php to make my query call, then in my index.php display the data in a foreach loop.

I was thinking perhaps using the query string to change the limit to rows 10-20 on click but finding difficulty in this.

Any help will be appreciated.

class query.php

```
     public function Query($db_table, $limit) {

        $this->db_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table ORDER BY time DESC limit $limit");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->db_query)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
  }
```

index.php

```
$lim = $_GET['limit'];
$Results = $Database->Query('info',  $lim); 
    if(is_array($Results)) {?>
   foreach ($Results as $Result) { 
  //echo results
```

jquery

```
$("#my_container").load("../lib/class.database.php?limit=10,20"  );
```

Kind regards, 
Adam

Comment: Go ahead and post the code you currently have, it will add clarity to the question.

Comment: What have you done so far? This is how to attack this problem: look at jquery and ajax. Understand how it works. Every time you hit "Load more results", a variabel must be updated, an ajax-call must be made. Query must select the right pictures (based on your variabel that you send along with your ajax-call). Echo the content and place the content in the right div using jQuery.

Comment: @Adam Please use at least `intval()` to avoid SQL injections: `$lim = intval($_GET['limit'])`. And you don't limit the number of images, so someone could overload your database! See my answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple:

#### 1.) You make an AJAX call to your PHP script

```
$.ajax(
{
  url: "get-ajax-images.php",
  data: "mode=ajax&start=10&end=20",

  success: function() { /* ... */ },
  error: function() { /* ... */ }
});
```

#### 2.) PHP: Load the data from the database based upon `start` and `end`

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

// Please use intval() to avoid SQL injections!!
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? intval($_GET['start']) : exit('{"error": true}');
$end = isset($_GET['end']) ? intval($_GET['end']) : exit('{"error": true}');

/* valid start and end? */
if ( $start < 0 || $end < 0 )
  exit('{"error": true}');

if ( ($end - $start) <= 0 ||
     ($end - $start) > 15 )
  exit('{"error": true}');


/* All right! */

$sql = "SELECT id, imagepath FROM images LIMIT $start, $end";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or exit('{"error": true}');

$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @bazmegakapa I don't think so. I convert `$_GET['start']` and `$_GET['end']` to integers!

Comment: @CommFreek Missed that one :). Removed downvote, but will leave my comments here. At least the OP and future readers will see the importance of `intval()` there (which was not emphasized, even though the OP committed this mistake in his code).

Comment: @bazmegakapa I added a comment in the code and wrote a comment to Adam :)

Comment: Why don't you guys just makeout

Comment: @Adam We are trying to save the damned soul of your code. [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jquery part for you question

http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/e5kXc/

it holds the total amount of loaded results and you could use the var's `limit` and `total` for quering the correct results